# What *IS* an answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged this answer as not an answer

[Is it safe to put hot food in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/is-it-safe-to-put-hot-food-in-the-fridge/40533#40533)

and received

```
declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
```

The alleged answer talks vaguely about some malfunctions in the posters refrigerator which he implies might be made worse by putting in hot food, but is completely unresponsive to the original question asked.  It does not in any realistic way address the actual question, which is clearly by being tagged [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) and by asking about bacterial growth a food safety question.

So what is the standard for being an answer?  Just vaguely talking about something that might sort of be related, if one has drunk enough beer?

Comment: I have also seen (as I mentioned in chat) a few instances where an "answer" in no way addresses the question, but will then generate very good comments (and then gets upvoted more for the comments than the "answer" itself).

Answer (score 1):

If filling your fridge with steam from hot food potentially *breaks* it, that's a food safety issue.

Now, maybe that's not the only cause of the problem, maybe it wouldn't normally happen, so it's probably not a *great* answer (probably has some technical inaccuracies or might even be altogether wrong) but it is a possible reason it would be unsafe to put hot food in your fridge, so it's an answer.

Comment: Agreed, the answer *does* address the question of "is it safe" (either for you or for your fridge). As the decline reason clearly indicates, the fact that it might be a poor or even a *wrong* answer doesn't justify a flag.